# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable what do i do?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I'm making a feed forward Neural network and I'm not sure why its not working:
 heres the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random 


#Hyperparameters
num_iterations = 100000
errors_shown = 1
num_iterations_per_error = num_iterations // errors_shown
learning_rate = 0.01

def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv == True:
        return x * (1 - x)
    else:
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
   #Input Data
x = np.array([[9, 2],
        [7, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [5, 0.5],
        [5, 0],
        [5.6, 0.7],
        [10, 0.5],
        [9, 0.5],
        [8, 3.7],
        [3, 0.5],
        [4, 2],
        [4, 2.5],
        [9, 2.5],
        [10, 0],
        [5, 1],
        [8, 3],
        [7, 1.7],
        [9, 0],
        [3, 3]])

#Output Data
y = np.array([[0.87],
            [0.12],
            [0.09],
            [0.12],
            [0.13],
            [0.47],
            [0.39],
            [0.36],
            [0.97],
            [0.19],
            [0.23],
            [0.67],
            [0.94],
            [0.33],
            [0.57],
            [0.91],
            [0.73],
            [0.63],
            [0.32]])

np.random.seed(1)

#Random synapses 
syn0 = np.random.random((2, 3))
syn1 = np.random.random((3, 4))
syn2 = np.random.random((4, 3))
syn3 = np.random.random((3, 2))
syn4 = np.random.random((2, 1))
syns = [syn0, syn1, syn2, syn3, syn4]

#Random bias'
b0 = np.random.random((1, 3))
b1 = np.random.random((1, 4))
b2 = np.random.random((1, 3))
b3 = np.random.random((1, 2))
b4 = np.random.random((1, 1))
bias = [b0, b1, b2, b3, b4]

#Neural Network

class NN:
    def __init__(self, input_data, expected_output_data, num_iterations, num_iterations_per_error, learning_rate, syns, bias):
        self.input_data = input_data
        self.expected_output_data = expected_output_data
        self.num_iterations = num_iterations
        self.num_iterations_per_error = num_iterations_per_error
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.syn0 = syns[0]
        self.syn1 = syns[1]
        self.syn2 = syns[2]
        self.syn3 = syns[3]
        self.syn4 = syns[4]
        self.b0 = bias[0]
        self.b1 = bias[1]
        self.b2 = bias[2]
        self.b3 = bias[3]
        self.b4 = bias[4]

#predict
def pred(self):
    self.l0 = self.input_data
    self.l1 = nonlin(np.dot(self.l0, self.syn0) + self.b0)
    self.l2 = nonlin(np.dot(self.l1, self.syn1) + self.b1)
    self.l3 = nonlin(np.dot(self.l2, self.syn2) + self.b2)
    self.l4 = nonlin(np.dot(self.l3, self.syn3) + self.b3)
    self.z = (np.dot(self.l4, self.syn4) + self.b4)

    self.pred = nonlin(self.z)

    return self.pred 

#Cost func
def cost_func(self):
    self.l4_error = np.square(self.l4 - self.expected_output_data)

    self.l4_delta = self.l4_error * nonlin(self.l4, deriv=True)

    self.l3_error = self.l4_delta.dot(self.syn3.T)

    self.l3_delta = self.l3_error * nonlin(self.l3, deriv=True)

    self.l2_error = self.l3_delta.dot(self.syn2.T)

    self.l2_delta = self.l2_error * nonlin(self.l2, deriv=True)

    self.l1_error = self.l2_delta.dot(self.syn1.T)

    self.l1_delta = self.l1_error * nonlin(self.l1, deriv=True)

    self.total_error += self.l4_error

    return self.l4_error

#Backprop 
def backprop(self):
    self.syn3 += self.l3.T.dot(self.l4_delta * self.learning_rate)
    self.syn2 += self.l2.T.dot(self.l3_delta * self.learning_rate)
    self.syn1 += self.l1.T.dot(self.l2_delta * self.learning_rate)
    self.syn0 += self.l0.T.dot(self.l1_delta * self.learning_rate)

def runner(self):
    self.total_error = 0

    for iteration in range(self.num_iterations): 
        pred = self.pred()
        cost = self.cost_func()
        self.backprop()

neuralNet = NN(x, y, num_iterations, num_iterations_per_error, learning_rate, syns, bias)

neuralNet.runner()
```

so I don't know what's wrong with it so can you please help me?
 this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-e63563ac83ed> in <module>
     72 neuralNet = NN(x, y, num_iterations, num_iterations_per_error, learning_rate, syns, bias)
     73 
---> 74 neuralNet.runner()

<ipython-input-55-e63563ac83ed> in runner(self)
     66 
     67         for iteration in range(self.num_iterations):
---> 68             pred = self.pred()
     69             cost = self.cost_func()
     70             self.backprop()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Please just post your answers in the thing down at the bottom
its in the def pred it says so yeah plz help and it s just a deep feed forward neural net

Comment: oops sorry I didn't indent the defs although they are actually inddented

Comment: What's stopping you from editing your post to fix the indentation?

Comment: Don't name your member `self.pred`, as `self.pred` is already a function. So for Python it seems that you are returning a function or calling a member.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here, in the function `self.pred`:

```
self.pred = nonlin(self.z)
return self.pred
```

The function `self.pred` replaces itself with a number or ndarray, since that's what `nonlin()` returns. That means you can only call `self.pred` once because it erases itself the first time it runs. Instead, don't use the function's name to store the result of the function, because then you're essentially replacing the function with a static result, which can't be called like a function.